# How can I make a label in an iOS renderer wrap around and resize?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have this code in an iOS Renderer:

```
    private class CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
    {
        public CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
        {
        }

        public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
                var lbl = new PaddedLabel()
                {

                    // Text = TitleForFooter(tableView, section), // or use some other text here
                    Text = "Select or deselect cards from the list above and they will added or removed from the card deck",
                    TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Justified,
                    LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap
                };
                return lbl;
        }

        public sealed class PaddedLabel : UILabel
        {
            private UIEdgeInsets EdgeInsets { get; set; } = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0);

            public override void DrawText(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
            {
                var newRect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, rect.Width + 10, rect.Height);
                base.DrawText(EdgeInsets.InsetRect(newRect));
            }
        }

    }
```

The code works but my label **does not wrap around** and I am guessing it **does not resize** also  Note that I did try adding WordWrap but that doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this and also make it autoresize.

Comment: Add `using UIKit;` at the top?

Comment: Thanks but I already have that at the top.

Comment: Doesn't sound very right.. Did you clean and rebuild etc?

Comment: Did a clean and rebuild and same result.  I'll include full code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `UILabel`, try using 'UITextView` - it's easier to integrate word-wrap with padding/insets.

```
private class CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
{
    public CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        var txtView = new UITextView
        {
            Editable = false,
            Text = "Select or deselect cards from the list above and they will added or removed from the card deck,",
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Justified,
            TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 5, right: 5),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent.ToUIColor()
        };

        txtView.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        return txtView;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great,  Thanks, I will look into this and let you know if I have any questions.  If not I will accept.

Comment: @SamanthaJTStar : Just an FYI. I had forgotten to set `Editable` as `false` in `UITextView` to keep it readonly like a label. I have added that now.

Comment: It seems like if the label is more than one line then it gets cut off and doesn't resize.  Do you have any idea what might be causing this? Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaJTStar : Can you please share sample text that's causing issues?

Comment: I'm looking into it now.  Seems like it usually works but I have one case where it does not work.  I will try to document that use case.

Answer (score 1):

> does not wrap around

It is because you forget to set `Lines` 0.

> does not resize

I think It is because  you increase the width when drawing.

Final code :

```
public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    var lbl = new PaddedLabel()
    {
         Lines = 0,
        // Text = TitleForFooter(tableView, section), // or use some other text here
        Text = "Select or deselect cards from the list above and they will added or removed from the card deck",
        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Justified,
        LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap
    };
    return lbl;
}

    public sealed class PaddedLabel : UILabel
    {
        private UIEdgeInsets EdgeInsets { get; set; } = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0);

        public override void DrawText(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
        {
            var newRect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, rect.Width , rect.Height);
            base.DrawText(EdgeInsets.InsetRect(newRect));
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Cole, I will wait a while and maybe add a bounty to the question.  Hopefully you or another person can get some ideas on why the word wrap doesn't work.

Comment: @SamanthaJTStar https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines the default value of Lines is 1, this is the reason why  the word wrap doesn't work. However, UITextView  doesn't have this property ,it word wraps automatically.